# PHP file_get_contents over network

Tags: php, windows, file-get-contents

I have XAMPP Server on Windows with IP Address : `192.168.184.215`

Then I have Log Data Server on Windows with IP Address : `192.168.184.13`

And now I'm running below PHP code(test.php) on browser from Log Data Server (call http://192.168.184.215/test.php):

```
fopen('\\\\192.168.184.13\\Test Folder\\a.txt', 'r');
```

- I have shared the Test Folder for Everyone access.

But I got error:

```
Warning: fopen(\\192.168.184.13\Test Folder\a.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I'm trying to open directly on windows explorer: `\\192.168.184.13\Test Folder\a.txt` it can be opened.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Notice that the error is about permissions. Your regular user ID is allowed to access the file, but the webserver user isn't.

Comment: @Barmar So, is there any possible how to allow it to be accessed?

Comment: Change the permissions on the file to allow it to be accessed by other network users.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I'm trying to set full access to Everyone user, Administrator, SYSTEM. But still can't

Comment: I don't know Windows system administration.

Comment: Try asking on [su].

Comment: At the start of your comment the third part of the IP is `185` but in your code it's looking for an IP part of `184`

Comment: @mulquin Sorry wrong typo. Updated it